# Is the current supplied by battery constant if I connect a battery to a capacitor and inductor in parallel?

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, batteries, inductor

If I connect an inductor and capacitor in parallel will the current supplied by battery be constant or will it die out? I have done some calculations which I have shown below here i assumed that total current supplied by battery is I:[image]

Here is dI/dt or I (dot) 0?

Comment: Depending on how ideal your models are, if the inductor has zero series resistance, then the battery current will grow to infinity eventually.

Comment: With ideal components like you have drawn, there is nothing to limit the current so it will keep growing to infinity via the inductance. Also at the moment of connection the capacitor gets charged to battery voltage, and since there is nothing to limit the current it will be infinite, and it will charge in no time at all, so dI is infinite and dt is zero.

Comment: @Justme yes of course silly of me to not draw any resistance

Comment: @Neil_UK but if we consider the scenario during charging as i have shown in the figure then wont the circuit start to ossilate??(during charging of course)???

Comment: @Justme but if we consider the scenario during charging as i have shown in the figure then wont the circuit start to ossilate??(during charging of course)???

Comment: **No oscillation**, because the battery voltage is well fixed (internal resistor = 0). You can make 2 separated circuits, one with the inductor, the other with the capacitor.

Comment: @Antonio51 Consider a real battery

Comment: Was not specified? Did not see ... Does all change ... Would also be a switch.

Comment: You should edit your question ... Unless error : ibat_t := U*(4*R^2*C-L-2*L*exp(-1/2*t/(R*C))*C*sqrt((4*R^2*C-L)/(L*C^2*R^2))*sin(1/2*sqrt((4*R^2*C-L)/(L*C^2*R^2))*t)*R)/(R*(4*R^2*C-L))  Plotted standardized ibat_t/(U/R)  -> with R:=10 Ohm; C:=1mF; L:=1mH; U:=10V   https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI7Bn.png

Comment: @Antonio51 I have edited the part as suggested and tried to solve but I am not yet capable to solve this end equation hence..... Btw are my calculations okay????

Comment: yeah ok no worries brother thankyou

Comment: @Damstridium --- Sorry, I said "you should update your question"... I would say " Ask a new question with the update of R and switch" ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *If I connect an inductor and capacitor in parallel will the current
> supplied by battery be constant or will it die out?*

For a quick answer, you don't need to consider the capacitor at all. If it alone were connected across the battery, it would rapidly charge to the battery voltage and then consume no current. So, the capacitor can be ignored.

The inductor on the other hand will draw a current that ramps up to infinity over time. Clearly, the battery cannot supply that so, whatever the maximum current output of the battery is, it will be the final current (possibly hundreds of amps).

Comment: in what kind of a scenario will there be LC oscillations in the circuit?

Comment: I was studying vaguely a transistor oscillator and it had a similar circuit and my teachers told me that this will come in detail in higher courses but they didn't explain why does the LC oscillations begin

Comment: Sir if we think of the circuit during charging of the capacitor wont it start LC ossilations? acc to my equasions??

Comment: I think you are considering the scenario after charging of the capacitor not during charging. Please let me know if this thing gets too complicated, if so then i will leave this for now

Comment: I think it will get complicated so..... I guess my question is solved then... thankyou

Comment: To make it oscillate, you need to put resistance between the battery and the parallel LC circuit or, run the LC from a current source. No, it's not too complex to answer these additional questions.

Comment: Sir will that finite resistance cause the current to become constant so my above equasion becomes an shm equasion???

Comment: if not then kindly illustrate if possible what will happen... or give me a hint. on how to solve the problem

Comment: I'm unsure what problem it is that you have to solve. Are you trying to design an oscillator? Are you trying to design a filter? I'm not sure where to take this. Anyway, don't despair because when you figure it out, I may be off-line (shopping with the missus) so, maybe ask a new question and get other folk to contribute. I'll be back in about 2 hours.

Comment: okay enjoy your time sir and thankyou  so much

Comment: btw i am trying to study an ossilator

Comment: OK, I'm good with oscillators but, there is little connection with this question without massive changes. I would suggest that you post a new question and show the circuit of the oscillator and explain what it is that you are struggling to understand. I'll be back in an hour and look forward to that question.

Answer (score 2):

The OP did not say that there was internal resistance in supply. Unless an error.

So, this is the case when R (internal resistance of supply) is not equal to zero and there is also a serial switch.

Plot is Relative current battery (current supply **ibat_t / (U/R)** ).

[image]

The case R=0 can be found making R -> 0 ...

Some plots: R = 10, 1, 0.1, with simulator. Some are relative plots ( **/(U/R**).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey brother can you check my work in the new image??

Comment: Sorry :-) I only use Laplace transform ... I am getting too old for some exercise :-)

Comment: yup thankyou anways...

Comment: @Damstridium --- Sorry, I said "you should update your question"... I would say " Ask a new question with the update of R and switch" ...

Comment: if you want your answer as accepted then brother i am going to ask a new question with the same thing. so reply there and i will mark it accepted

Comment: we both know what you need to do if you want the credit

Comment: i am redy when you do

Comment: I have posted the question again kindly answer it there bro

Comment: @Damstridium   Don't worry about ... I don't search "reputation", Thanks. <<< Help each other ... for the "good of all" ! >>> Don't know if it is the "right sentence". Somebody, in the old times, says something as this.

Comment: so it rings like a bell with arbitrary quality factor Q when switched.   At some point it becomes stable. At this point current can be said to be stable and constant. Only at make or break do we see choke/charge behavior.

Comment: @mckenzm Yup so its kind of a dying oscillator right?

Comment: @Damstridium yes, although some prefer "decay".